# 2nd product on cart -50% based on category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need create function in WooCommerce - 50% discount to 2nd product, if 2nd product is from category 'odziez' slug. Can anyone help me? This code not work:

```html
<?php
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'ts_add_custom_discount', 10, 1 );
function ts_add_custom_discount( $wc_cart ){
    $discount = 0;
    $product_ids = array();
 $in_cart = false;
 foreach ( $wc_cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
  $cart_product = $cart_item['data'];
  if ( has_term( 'get2', 'product_cat', $cart_product->get_id() ) ) {
   $in_cart = true;
  }else {
   $product_ids[] = $cart_product->get_id();
  }
 }
 if( $in_cart ) {
  $count_ids = count($product_ids);
  if( $count_ids >= 1 ) { 
     foreach( $product_ids as $id ) {
       
    $product = wc_get_product( $id );
    $price = $product->get_price();
    $discount -= ($price * 50) /100; //apply 50% discount on the other product
     }
    }
 } 
    if( $discount != 0 ){
        $wc_cart->add_fee( 'Discount', $discount, true  );
        # Note: Last argument in add_fee() method is related to applying the tax or not to the discount (true or false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi marcin, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please put the code in your post, for future reference. Also, what part of your code isn't working?

Comment: Discount not work, this code work for me (without category): https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45255823/revisions

Comment: You speak of category `odziez`, but I only see category `get2` in your code? And you calculate discount over products that are NOT of `get2`?

Comment: I replace 'get2' to 'odziez' and discount not work, in category 'odziez' i have 9 subcategories, need for all discount prices.

Comment: And what do you mean by 2nd product? Every second product? And only if both are from category `odziez`?

Comment: 2nd product must by category 'odziez', otherwise discount has no use.

Comment: Yes, but what about the first product? No odziez? Or also Odziez? Or doesn't matter? And what if there are 4 products? And what if someone orders more than 2 of it?

Comment: The first product must be clothing, the second also, and in the case of four products the second and fourth ... also 50%. It would be good for this more expensive product to have a normal price and for a cheaper discount.

Comment: How do you detect a clothing product? Is it in a category? What you ask about cheaper/expensive product is out of the scope of this question, to be honest.

Comment: I am sorry, your question is a little under specified.

Comment: Ok, see answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here I apply discount to less than or equal to half the amount of products. Discount only if a product is of category `odziez`.

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'ts_add_custom_discount', 10, 1 );
function ts_add_custom_discount( $wc_cart ){
    $discount = 0;
    $product_ids_with_price = array();
    $product_ids = array();
    $in_cart = false;

    $total_odziez = 0;
    $total_discounted = 0;
    // count nr of odziez
    foreach ( $wc_cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $cart_product = $cart_item['data'];
        if ( has_term( 'odziez', 'product_cat', $cart_product->get_id() ) ) {
            $total_odziez += $cart_item['quantity'];
        }
    }
    foreach ( $wc_cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $cart_product = $cart_item['data'];
        $prod_id = $cart_product->get_id();
        $_product = wc_get_product( $prod_id ); 
        $price = $_product->get_price();
        if ( has_term( 'odziez', 'product_cat', $prod_id ) ) {
            $product_ids_with_price[$cart_product->get_id()] = $price;
        }
    }

    asort($product_ids_with_price); // sort by price, so we get cheapest on top

    foreach ( $product_ids_with_price as $prod_id => $prod_price ) {
        if ($total_discounted < floor($total_odziez / 2)) {  // Starting from the cheapest, add products for discounting until you have done half of all odziez products
            $total_discounted++;
            $product_ids[] = $prod_price;
            $in_cart = true;
        }    
    }

    if( $in_cart ) {
        $count_ids = count($product_ids);
        if( $count_ids >= 1 ) { 
           foreach( $product_ids as $id => $price ) {

                // $product = wc_get_product( $id );
                // $price = $product->get_price();
                $discount -= ($price * 50) /100; //apply 50% discount on the other product
           }
       }
    } 
    if( $discount != 0 ){
        $wc_cart->add_fee( 'Discount', $discount, true  );
        # Note: Last argument in add_fee() method is related to applying the tax or not to the discount (true or false)
    }
}
```

**Update**

Changed it so it discounts every 2nd item of category `odziez`.

**Update**

I added that the cheapest products get discounted over the more expensive ones.